# Why do I keep getting wget-log file in ~ on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, logs, configuration, wget

I have noticed on my Arch Linux (with GNOME 3.24.2 and GDM) installation that my `~` is filled with files like this and they keep increasing:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    0 May  8 00:01 wget-log
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    0 May  8 00:01 wget-log.1
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    0 May  8 00:01 wget-log.2
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    0 May  8 00:01 wget-log.3
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    0 May  8 00:01 wget-log.4
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    0 May  8 20:04 wget-log.5
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    0 May  8 20:04 wget-log.6
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    0 May  8 20:04 wget-log.7
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    0 May  8 20:04 wget-log.8
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    0 May  8 20:04 wget-log.9
```

In fact, there would be more if I didn't delete them every day. I have noticed these files appearing after running `sudo pacman -Syu`, but I have also observed them not appearing after doing so so perhaps it was just coincidence? But I would really like to track down the cause of these empty log files appearing in `~` as they are actually quite annoying and seem to serve no real purpose.

So what are they caused by and is there any way I get either stop them from appearing or have them do so in a different location?

Comment: Do you have `sysdig`? If so, run `sudo sysdig -p "%proc.pname(%proc.ppid) %proc.name(%proc.pid)" "fd.name contains wget-log"` and see what process is poking those files.

Comment: My guess is you have a cron job that runs every day at 0:00 and 20:00 and does some kind of `wget`.

Comment: @thrig: Seems to be a problem with that, I have updated my question to provide more information.

Comment: @thrig: It appears as though the `sysdig` DKMS module now builds successfully so I will try running it and let you know of the results.

Comment: @thrig: It's been running now for a few hours and still no output. How long is this command expected to run for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug, a regression from wget 1.18 to wget 1.19.1 which is used by Arch Linux. I have opened a bug report here: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?51181

This bug is fixed in Wget 1.19.3, [released](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-wget/2018-01/msg00027.html) on 19 January 2018.